# Oracle: What should I know about SGA?

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is SGA? Can you explain me in a simple manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/memory.htm) does a pretty good job. An excerpt follows:

> The SGA comprises a number of memory components, which are pools of
>   memory used to satisfy a particular class of memory allocation
>   requests. Examples of memory components include the shared pool (used
>   to allocate memory for SQL and PL/SQL execution), the java pool (used
>   for java objects and other java execution memory), and the buffer
>   cache (used for caching disk blocks).